# Mapping Many to many relationship with single model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, mapping, many-to-many

My model

```
public class Student
    {
        public int id{ get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }

        public string Qualification{ get; set; }

   }
```

In my project i am trying to create partners of student where a student can be partner with any number of student. i know i can achieve that by creating another model like this

```
 public class Partners
    {

        public string student1ID{ get; set; }

        public string student2ID{ get; set; }

   }
```

And insert values but just want to know if is there any other way to achieve this using virtual list<> etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a relation like each student will have one or more partners you can do this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Qualification{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Partner> Partners{ get; set; }     
}

public class Partner
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: actually i was looking for solution where i dont have to create another model.

Comment: @aradhanalohan, You don't create another model - you fix the mistakes in your current model

Comment: yes right  but this is one solution i was wondering if mvc allow another solution where i dont have to create partner class just using student only is it possible?

Comment: since i am creating many to many relation for class itself so is there any other way to have this configured within same class, hope you are getting my question